# How to set gross price to google play subscription item

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

If I set price for a subscription item in google play console, it doesn't include tax. I'd like to set the same price what user will see in the app.
It works fine with in-app products if I use templates, but I can't find solution for subscription items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I realized that it's not possible to give a tax included price for a subscription item in google play console. If I give a price, system will also show me that with the taxes. So the only way is that I have to play with it a bit.